# Tengo problemas en instalar Squirrelmail

Tags: ubuntu, servidor, debian

Error: **E: No se ha podido localizar el paquete squirrelmail**

He estado intentado instalar Squirrelmail en mí Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS, mi repositorio está en "universe", justo lo acabo de actualizar y me sigue saliendo el mismo error, al instalar cualquier otra cosa no tengo ningún problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿Saben de que manera puedo instalarlo?**

Comment: Parece que SquirrelMail no está disponible para Ubuntu 18.04 oficialmente, no sé si hayas encontrado forma de instalarlo... También me gustaría saberlo.